# Threading and pyfsevents

Tags: python, macos, multithreading

The module [pyfsevents](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfsevents) allows Python programs to utilize the Mac OS X FSEvents framework. One can register a path and a callback function, then call the listen() function, which blocks until a file system event happens in the registered path.

```
    pyfsevents.registerpath("/example", callback)
    pyfsevents.listen()
```

I would like to use this module in a multithreaded program, having one thread blocking and waiting for file system events, then notifying another thread to handle the event. Unfortunately, it looks like listen() blocks the entire program, not just the calling thread. Can anyone confirm this? Is there a way to block only the calling thread? If not, are there ways to achieve similar functionality, i.e. letting a thread detect changes in a directory, preferably without polling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as [the docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfsevents/0.2b1) say (under "Limitations"),

> Thread-unsafe: CFRunLoop's and Python
>   threads do not quite interact well
>   when put together :)

What I recommend is using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing) to isolate the `pyfsevents` use in a dedicated process, which can send "heads-up" alerts to the main process in any way you please (e.g., via a `multiprocessing.Queue`).

If you need to run on Python 2.5, there's a [backport](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/2.6.2.1) of the `multiprocessing` module -- the latter's in the standard library only since Python 2.6, but the backport runs fine on 2.4 and 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try out MacFSEvents. It is thread-safe. https://github.com/malthe/macfsevents